# Ansible: Skip loop when list is undefined

Tags: ansible

Example playbook -

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    lesson:
     name: Physics
     students:
      - Bob
      - Joe

  tasks:
     - name: Display student names
       debug:
         msg: '{{ item }}'
       loop: "{{ lesson.students }}"
       when: item | default("")
```

The above playbook works well to output the student names.

However, if the input changes (as per below) such that no student names have been defined, then an error occurs. Is there a simple way to have the playbook skip this task if the list is undefined as per the input below? I realize it would work if the input specifies **students: []**, but as this input is coming from simple users, they're not going to know this. Much Thanks!

```yaml
  vars:
    lesson:
     name: Physics
     students:
```

> Error: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
> msg: 'Invalid data passed to ''loop'', it requires a list, got this instead: . Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup.

Update - I've tried the below variations but still get the same error -

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    lesson:
     name: Physics
     students:

  tasks:
     - name: Display student names variation 1
       debug:
         msg: '{{ item }}'
       loop: "{{ lesson.students }}"
       when: lesson.students is iterable

     - name: Display student names variation 2
       debug: 
         msg: '{{ item }}'
       loop: "{{ lesson.students }}"
       when: lesson.students is not none

     - name: Display student names variation 3
       debug: 
         msg: '{{ item }}'
       loop: "{{ lesson.students }}"
       when: ( item | default("") ) or ( item is not none )
```

Comment: The "loop" directive is evaluated before the "when" condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real problem is that `loop` **requires** a list, even if it is an empty list.

If your var is undefined/None/empty string, it exists but is not a list and your when condition will never get evaluated because loop will fire an error before it is ever reached.

You have to default your var to an empty list in such cases, which will lead to a 0 size loop equivalent to skipping the task.

Since your var is defined but `None` you need to use the [second optional parameter to `default`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) so that empty/false values are replaced as well

*Note: I used the short alias `d` to `default` in my below examples*

```yaml
     - name: Display student names
       debug:
         msg: '{{ item }}'
       loop: "{{ lesson.students | d([], true) }}"
```

A good practice here that would have nipped that error in the bud would be to have a coherent data declaration by either:

1. not declaring the key at all and use a simple default i.e.

   ```yaml
   # ... #
   vars:
     lesson:
       name: Physics
   # ... #
          loop: "{{ lesson.students | d([]) }}"
   ```
2. declare an empty list for the key rather than a `None` value i.e.

   ```yaml
   # ... #
   vars:
     lesson:
       name: Physics
       students: []
   # ... #
          loop: "{{ lesson.students }}"
   ```

My first proposition is the safest in this case anyway and will work for all the above vars declarations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between an `undefined` variable, and variable having `None` value.

When you set variable name, but leave the right hand side empty. The variable *is defined*, but it is set to `NoneType`.

So your `when:` condition should have additional check for `NoneType`:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    lesson:
     name: Physics
     students:

  tasks:
     - name: Display student names
       debug:
         msg: '{{ item }}'
       loop: "{{ lesson.students }}"
       when: ( item | default("") ) or ( item is not none )
```

This will give:

```
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tested this and still get the same error. My ansible version is 2.9.4.

Comment: This will not work when `lessons.students` exists but is None (as in OP's answer and has you understood) because the loop is evaluated first and will fire an error (i.e. "I need a list!!!!") before any when condition is ever reached. See my answer.